# Efficient object-space hidden surface removal

Tags: performance, algorithm, surface

I have the following problem: I need to generate 2d views of a 3d model. Under normal cicrcumstances this would of course be trivial: just render everything to the screen using the painter's algorithm or a similar technique. Unfortunately, the output needs to be 2d geometry so that it can be sent to CAD packages. This means that the hidden surface removal must be done on the vector level rather than the pixel level, which renders most of the standard methods (painter's algorithm, z-buffer, etc.) unusable.

The most common technique I found to perform object-space hidden surface removal is to use a BSP tree, which in theory works just fine. So I implemented that, but performance wasn't even remotely acceptable, which isn't entirely surprising given its O(n<sup>2</sup>) complexity. The test scene I'm using has about 4800 triangles after backface culling, but I expect the algorithm will need to handle scenes with about 5 or 10 times that number, which quickly becomes rather large when you need to square it. The (lack of) speed of our geometry library doesn't exactly help either.

I've since tried different ways of trying to work around this performance problem, mainly based around the idea of dividing up the triangles in smaller groups to reduce the impact of the O(n<sup>2</sup>), such as octrees (over half the polygons were stored in the root node) and dividing the 2d-projected scene in a 10x10 grid to reduce the number of triangles per square (works, but the reduction in polygon intersections is outweighed by the need to repeat the process a 100 times).

Today I had another go by projecting all the triangles to 2D and seeing which ones intersect by first testing if the bounding squares overlap and then testing each edge intersection (3x3 = 9) for every combination of two polygons. For the line intersection I bypassed the geometry library by using the algorithm described [here](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/). In total, about 11.6 million line intersections are performed, taking about 30 seconds, which is still far too long (I'd say the absolute maximum runtime would be around 5 seconds), never mind that this is only part of the algorithm.

I'm starting to run out of ideas on how to solve this performance problem and was hoping that any of you would have some good ideas for a better algorithm. All of the ones I can think of are all O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Can you provide some more implementation specifics (languages, libaries, etc...) ?

Comment: What is the typical number of surfaces that are actually visible in the 2D view?

Comment: I'm working in C#. The geometry library was written by the company I work for and is not open source. It's also written in C# and supports basic operations such as polygon intersection, albeit not in an exceedingly fast manner. The geometry library is not particularly important though, since I can just ignore it and work with the x-, y- and z-coordiantes of the triangle points directly if need be. I don't think the language matters much either. The problem is mainly one of algorithms. It should be fairly trivial to port any solution to C#.

Comment: The mentioned 4,800 triangles that face the camera will probably be around the average case. I don't know how much of those are occluded by other surfaces, but I'd say the average number of visible triangles in the final view would be around 3,000 or so, with the worst case being maybe some 30,000-odd triangles. The test object I used is a window + frame with a fairly complex profile, which means that most of the triangles are located at the edges of the model. The part where the panes of glass are only has a handful of polygons.

Comment: @FalconNL: Does my answer bring anything to your initial problem? You did not provided feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party but if this was never solved my suggestion would be to use a shadow matrix and project the geometry onto a plane that way you've got a 2D representation of the 3D scene from a given orientation without going to screen space / pixels yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a modified Bresenham algorithm, where you compute for a line all pixels crossed (maybe this algorithm has a name btw). The complete method would be then:

1. Create a `n x m` spatial index (with a sorted list of polygons per grid), with n and m quite large (let's say 1000x1000 cells).
2. For each projected polygon, use the "modified Bresenham algorithm" above to add the polygon to all cells it crosses.
3. Create a set of pairs of potential polygon intersections by looking at all pairs in each cell.
4. Make the proper real intersection test, only for potential pairs found in the previous step.

Step 3 should ensure that you prune to a maximum the number of potential intersections. Step 2 is O(n) and should be quite fast for small polygons (small number of crossed cells).

You can even dynamically tweak your spatial index grid size, looking at previous results and/or heuristics based on number of total polygons, average polygon size, etc...

Comment: Yeah, I already tried a grid-based subdivision method (albeit with fewer cells). Unfortunately, the shapes in question (window frames) are such that most polygons are located at the edges, which means that such a grid-based appraoch actually increased the amount of work. Since no amount of optimization I could come up with managed to result in acceptable performance we have decided to abandon the 3D-based algorithm and compose the views from the views of the individual parts of the window.